# How do you disable the zoom effect / window animations in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, desktop-effects

How do you disable the zoom effect / window animations in the OS X Lion?

Comment: Which window animation?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the new animations for opening and closing windows, they can be disabled with `defaults write -g NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool false`.

Note that it makes the lookup popovers sometimes stay visible until windows are closed; sometimes showing them even makes applications crash.

Comment: defaults read NSGlobalDomain |grep -i anim

Answer (score 3):

I Would recommend installing [Secrets Pref Pane](https://code.google.com/archive/p/blacktree-secrets/downloads) it gives you access to loads of hidden options in Mac OS X. you will find the "Animate Window Zooms" option under the "Finder" section.

[image]

Comment: That's basically the same as `defaults write -g NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool false` mentioned in my answer

Comment: They both achieve the same thing yes, I find the prefpane is more convenient.